# calculating Date in salesforce

Tags: date

I have 2 fields Day of year, Date of year.
I want the logic to be build as

1. If i enter day of year = 50
2. In date field i should get as 19/02/2015

**50 th day of year is 19th Feb.**

This should change according to leap year

If your current year is non leap year then

1. If i enter day of year = 61
2. In date field i should get as 02/03/2015

**61st day of non leap year is 2nd April.**

If your current year is leap year

1. If i enter day of year = 61
2. In date field i should get as 01/03/2015

**61st day of leap year 1st of April.**

Regards,
Neha

Comment: are you doing this in apex ? or in a formula field ? if you can share what you have tried so far, we can suggest what needs to be fixed / changed

Comment: I m trying to do that using apex.

Comment: Could you share your code so far, and tell us where you're blocked ?  Just dropping some requirements here and expecting someone to write the code for you isn't going to help you learn to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In Apex you could do the following:

```
Integer dayOfYear = 50;
Datetime startDate = Datetime.newInstance(2015, 1, 1);
Datetime dayOfYearDate = startDate.addDays(dayOfYear - 1);

System.debug(dayOfYearDate); // Returns 2015-02-19
```

I guess you probably want to set the year for the starting point to the current year, in which case you'd need to change the line to:

```
Datetime startDate = Datetime.newInstance(Datetime.now().year(), 1, 1);
```

Comment: The OP was asking for `Date` rather than `DateTime` but your code will work if `Date` is used instead of `DateTime`. Except for `Datetime.now()` which would need to be `Date.today()`