# Formula field to check date is passed or not

Tags: workflow, formula-field, salesforce-classic

Hi I have `start_Date__c` which specify project is started.
I want formula field to check whether `End_Date__c` is passed or not. If it is passed then i want to uncheck the checkbox. 
For example if end date is `30/6/2017` it should be checked meaning project is going on and if date is `1/5/2017`, it should get uncheck.

Comment: So, do you want to have a formula checkbox or just a checkbox?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Formula field should be Check box type and you can improve logic if( start_Date__c <= End_Date__c ,true,false)..true will make check box is checked and false will uncheck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating Date in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72288/calculating-date-in-salesforce)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? A formula will not cause a trigger to fire. If you just want it to evaluate when the record is being viewed then a formula will work. If you want to fire a process when the time period has passed then a formula field will not do what you want.

Comment: @Eric, I have the same requirement, Process should fire when the time period has passed then formula field should update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formula field datatype as a checkbox.

1. If you want to validate its endDate with current date then and place this formula in the editor
   `IF(End_Date__c > TODAY() , true, false)`
2. If you want to validate its endDate with start date then and place this formula in the editor
   `IF(End_Date__c > start_Date__c , true, false)`